# How to connect Mongo DB through Oracle DB?

Tags: mongodb, oracle, dblink

I need to access data in Mongo DB through Oracle DB. Can you guys help me to create a link between Mongo & Oracle?

Comment: What operating system is the Oracle database running on.  If there is a Mongo DB ODBC driver that runs on the operating system Oracle is using you should be able to use Heterogeneous Services to create a database link from Oracle to Mongo DB.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, still I haven't installed the Mongo DB ODBC driver.

Comment: You'll want to look at the Heterogeneous Connectivity User's Guide for information on how to set up the database link https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/heter/index.html If you have a specific question during the setup, we can probably address that here (though it would likely be more on topic over on the DBA stack).

Comment: Also note that Oracle is not certified to run on Ubuntu.  Beyond certification, Ubuntu is an entirely different branch of the LInux family tree from that which oracle was designed for.  Getting oracle to run at all on Ubuntu is a hack, and even if you get it up and running, results of any additional configuration/operation is never assured.  You'd be far better off doing what I do. Use VirtualBox to create a VM and install _oracle_ linux , then the database, on that.  Treat it just like you would a server in your data center.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install an MongoDB ODBC driver. You can install the ODBC driver from Mongo: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-odbc-driver

However, this ODBC driver works only for Mongo Atlas, i.e. MongoDB Cloud service, see [MongoDB ODBC Driver](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/odbc-driver-for-the-mongodb-connector-for-business-intelligence). If you have a local MongoDB then you cannot use it. In this case you have to go for one of the commercial third party Mongo ODBC drivers:

- Progress: https://www.progress.com/odbc/mongodb
- CData: https://www.cdata.com/drivers/mongodb/odbc/
- devart: https://www.devart.com/odbc/mongodb/
- EasySoft: https://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-mongodb-driver/index.html
- Simba: https://www.simba.com/drivers/mongodb-odbc-jdbc/

Then you can use the [Oracle Database Gateway for ODBC](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/odbcu/database-gateway-for-odbc-introduction.html) for the connection.

As far as I understand the "Oracle Database Gateway for ODBC" is one of the possible Heterogeneous Service Agents of the "Database Heterogeneous Connectivity" mentioned by Justin Cave.