# I am having trouble connecting MongoDB through mongosqld (BI Connector)

Tags: mongodb, tableau-api

I am trying to connect to mongodb using the mongosqld.
I used the command: mongosqld --mongo-uri "(host):(port)/?connect=direct" --auth /mongo-authenticationSource:"admin" /u "username" /p "password"
but it does not connect.
It keeps repeating [sampler] sampling MongoDB for schema over and over

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCImI.png)

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: Do you have MongoDB installed on your local machine on in cloud (MongoDB Atlas)?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, I  have mongodb installed in my computer.

Comment: The BI Connector is only working with Mongo Atlas (i.e. MongoDB cloud service). Local MongoDB is not supported, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67230688/3027266

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit It actually used to work just like a month ago. 
Now I can successfully connect with a normal read only authentication. But this problem occurs when I try to connect with the admin authentication.